# Storing Value from JSON response to AsyncStorage React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I am trying to store a userid (type Number) in AsyncStorage but this throws an error below:

Exception '-[_NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000023 was thrown while invoking multiset on target

AsyncLocalStorage with params (((userid, 2))

Please help me resolve this.

```js
class SignIn extends Component {

  loginHandler = async () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    try {
      let { data } = await axios
        .post("http://offer.kdamjibhai.com/api/login", {
          username: this.state.username,
          password: this.state.password
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data.status_code === 200) {
            if (response.data.data.status === "success") {
              //alert('came here ')
              AsyncStorage.setItem("loggedIn", "true");
              AsyncStorage.setItem('userid', response.data.data.user_info.user_id);
              
              this.setState({ loading: false });
              this.props.navigation.navigate("SignedIn");
            } 
          } else {
            alert(response.data.data.message);
            this.setState({ loading: false });
          }
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    
  };

  render() {}

}

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: do you have an account of your api for testing?

Comment: ys url : http://offer.kdamjibhai.com/api/login
username : vipul
password : 123456 

you will get response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried your code, the useid returned is Number, and AsyncStorage can only store strings. So you need to convert userid to string and then you can save. You should use `.then().catch()` to handle error instead of `try{} catch{}` and remove `async, await` keywords since you are using `.then().catch()` syntax.

```
loginHandler = () => {
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  axios
  .post("http://offer.kdamjibhai.com/api/login", {
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.data.status_code === 200) {
      if (response.data.data.status === "success") {
        //alert('came here ')
        AsyncStorage.setItem("loggedIn", "true");
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userid', response.data.data.user_info.user_id.toString());
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        this.props.navigation.navigate("SignedIn");
      }
    } else {
      alert(response.data.data.message);
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting value Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": "2",
  "_65": 1,
  "_72": null,
} 

while I use console log AsyncStorage.getItem('userid');

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to store object or number in AsyncStorage. AsyncStorage support only string to save. If `user_id` is number, convert it to string or use `JSON.stringify` before save to AsyncStorage.

You can first transform your response to a string with `JSON.stringify` and when you retrieve the object again you can use `JSON.parse` to get the object again.

Comment: I tried with JSON.stringify but getting this response 
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}

While I use `console.log(AsyncStorage.getItem('userid'))`

Comment: AsyncStorage.getItem() is asynchronous, so you need to await for it before logging: const userid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userid'); console.log(userid); Now you are logging a Promise object to the console

Comment: @Kedar Dave, your comment seems different from your question. In question you are asking about setItem and in comment you are telling about getItem. But still for your comment, getItem return a promise, you should handle promise and do on that promise result